# forever for nodeJs not working in ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, forever

I Installed [forever](https://www.npmjs.org/package/forever) module using npm globally in my ubuntu server as super user. But i can not start my nodeJs Appliation using this. I typed "forever" in my terminal, but seems like no commands were executed. am sure that i not faced any errors while "forever" instalation.
Please see the below output.
I tried the same in my local machine. But it works fine. am using Express 4.

forever in ubuntu server:-

[image]

forever in my local machine ouptput as follows:-

[image]

Is there any server settings i need to do it to work?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Myself got the answer. i did link between  node and nodejs by:-

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node
```

Comment: i also installed forever and i did nothing like this..Actually whats is this??

Comment: This is because things installed via npm want the Node.JS interpreter to be named "node" while the version installed by apt is named "nodejs"

Comment: superb !! i wasted 2 hours finding solution, finally this worked out. many thanks