# start forever command on ubuntu to run js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu-14.04, forever, forever-monitor

I have installed **forever** and **forever-monitor** on **ubuntu** in below path `/var/www/html/node_modules`

Now I try to start file which is at this path `/var/www/html/` with name `test.js`:
`forever start test.js`

But nothing happens. I have **globally installed** `forever`. Where am I wrong?

in `test.js` i have this js code:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  response.end('testing. . .\n');
}).listen(8124);

console.log('Server running...');
```

tried this command `ps -eaf | grep node` and output:

```
root     17101 16778  0 06:32 pts/0    00:00:00 nodejs chat_client.js
root     17318 16778  0 07:07 pts/0    00:00:00 nodejs my_queue_worker.js
root     17326 16778  0 07:08 pts/0    00:00:00 nodejs chat_client.js
root     17808 16778  0 07:50 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto node
```

Comment: can you issue the command - `forever list` and see what it says. Does it list your process?

Comment: `ps -eaf | grep node` - does it show the process?

Comment: @BatScream it is giving me this `root     17101 16778  0 06:32 pts/0    00:00:00 nodejs chat_client.js
root     17318 16778  0 07:07 pts/0    00:00:00 nodejs my_queue_worker.js
root     17326 16778  0 07:08 pts/0    00:00:00 nodejs chat_client.js
root     17798 16778  0 07:49 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto node
`

Comment: @BatScream any other solution?

Comment: Problem has been solved using this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863945/forever-for-nodejs-not-working-in-ubuntu-server